# TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined - react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

←→1 of 3 errors on the page

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

```
App.inputChangeHandler
src/App.js:37
  34 | 
  35 | inputChangeHandler(index,event){
  36 | const mProducts = this.state.product;
> 37 | mProducts[index].eName = event.target.value;
     | ^  38 | this.setState({
  39 |   product:mProducts
  40 | })
View compiled
▶ 22 stack frames were collapsed.
```

Comment: add component code,not getting from this much

Comment: replace const to let  ,you cant mutate const variables value

Comment: Code looks good. Can you show the input where you have added `inputChangeHandler`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437037/typeerror-cannot-set-property-ename-of-undefined-app-inputchangehandler
This is the full code link

Answer (score 0):

I believe that such error is triggered when you forgot to pass `event` while calling the function.

I think your input looks like this,

```
<input onChange={() => this.inputChangeHandler(1)} value={this.state.value} />
```

Here you have not provided `event`, which will give you the error

> Error: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

You should provide the `event` like,

```
<input onChange={(event) => this.inputChangeHandler(1,event)} value={this.state.value} />
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xar8lk)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58437037/typeerror-cannot-set-property-ename-of-undefined-app-inputchangehandler

Hi, Can you please click on this link I have the full code display. It is not updating the eName. When I input on from box.