# TypeError: Cannot set property 'eName' of undefined App.inputChangeHandler

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Once the user updates the input inbox displayed eName should change. It is not updating the array. What is causing this?

Error message:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'eName' of undefined App.inputChangeHandler

Code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state= {
    product:[
      {eName:"Anu", eNo:"1200", eSalary:"1000"},
      {eName:"Jack", eNo: "1201", eSalary:"1200"},
      {eName:"Ben", eNo: "1202", eSalary:"1300"}
    ],
    showFlag:true,
  }

  inputChangeHandler(event,index){
    const mProducts = this.state.product;
    mProducts[index].eName = event.target.value;
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
       product:mProducts
    })
  }

  deleteHandler(index){
    console.log("delete clicked" + index);
    const mProducts = this.state.product;
    mProducts.splice(index,1);
    this.setState({
      product:mProducts
    })
  }

  showHideHandler=()=>{
    this.setState({
      showFlag:!this.state.showFlag
    })
    console.log(this.state.showFlag);
  }

  render(){
    let dp = null;
    if (this.state.showFlag === true){
      dp =(
        <div className ="App">
          {this.state.product.map((product,index) => {
            return (
            <Product
              eName={product.eName}
              eNo={product.eNo}
              eSalary={product.eSalary}
              key ={index}
              click ={this.deleteHandler.bind(this.index)}
              inputChange={this.inputChangeHandler.bind(this)}
            />)
          })}
        </div>
      )
    }
    return(
      <div className ="App">
        {dp}
        <hr/>
        <button onClick={()=>this.showHideHandler()}>show hide</button>
        <h2>{this.state.eName} </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Once the user updates the input inbox displayed eName should change. It is not updating the array.

Comment: It will not allow me to remove the unformatted code block because there is not enough detail. Please add any steps you've tried, and remove the unformatted code.

Comment: For example, what are the values `inputChangeHandler` receives? is `key` defined? Is `mProducts` defined?

Comment: In the <Product/> are you sending the index here ```inputChange={this.inputChangeHandler.bind(this)}``` ?

Comment: Can you post your Product component?

Comment: import React from 'react'
import './employee.css'
function Employee(props) {
    return (
    <div className ="prod">
        <h1> Name:{props.eName}</h1>
        <h2> Emp-No:{props.eNo}</h2>
        <h3> Salary:{props.eSalary}</h3>
        <button onClick ={props.click}> delete</button>
        <input onChange={props.inputChange} type="text"/>

        </div>
    )
}
export default Employee;

Comment: Hi Anushika, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `inputChangeHandler` function is not receiving the correct index. Please make the below changes:

define `inputChangeHandler` function as arrow function:

```
inputChangeHandler = (event,index) => {
    const mProducts = this.state.product;
    mProducts[index].eName = event.target.value;
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
       product:mProducts
    })
  }
```

Inside `render` function, while calling `inputChangeHandler`, pass both event and index

```
render(){
        let dp = null;
        if (this.state.showFlag === true){
          dp =(
            <div className ="App">
              {this.state.product.map((product,index) => {
                return (
                <Product
                  eName={product.eName}
                  eNo={product.eNo}
                  eSalary={product.eSalary}
                  key ={index}
                  click ={this.deleteHandler.bind(this.index)}
                  inputChange={(e) => this.inputChangeHandler(e, index)}
                />)
              })}
            </div>
          )
        }
        return(
          <div className ="App">
            {dp}
            <hr/>
            <button onClick={()=>this.showHideHandler()}>show hide</button>
            <h2>{this.state.eName} </h2>
          </div>
        );
}
```

Comment: You're bit wrong here. `Product` is a component, no use of passing event here as you did.

Comment: @ravibagul91 He is passing an anonymous function that receives event and has index available as closure. Not the best way to pass handlers (see [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)). There is also a problem of the handler mutating state and then setting it, this could cause buggy behavior when the code is optimized not to re render when nothing changed (mutation is detected as change).

Comment: I get the following error. Because of the arrow function. /src/App.js
  Line 16:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "{"

  14 |  }
  15 | 
> 16 |  inputChangeHandler(index,event) =>{
     |                                  ^
  17 |     const mProducts = this.state.product;
  18 |     mProducts[index].eName = event.target.value;
  19 |     console.log(event.target.value);

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating state and do a setState with the mutated state in all your handlers. Because React does not see a change in state it won't re render (try to put a console.log in render and you'll see it won't show in console).

Here is how you set a value in state without mutating it:

```
inputChangeHandler(event, index) {
  this.setState({
    product: this.state.product.map((product, i) =>
      i === index
        ? { ...product, eName: event.target.value }
        : product
    ),
  });
}
```

I would advice better naming for your variable, if you have a list of products it would be better to call it `products` (plural) instead of `product` (single).

If you have React render a list of elements and you can delete or sort elements then you should not use index as key, doesn't product have a unique id you can use and if not then why not?

Below is an example of how you could send event handlers to Product:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    products: [
      { id: 1, eName: 'Anu', eNo: '1200', eSalary: '1000' },
      {
        id: 2,
        eName: 'Jack',
        eNo: '1201',
        eSalary: '1200',
      },
      { id: 3, eName: 'Ben', eNo: '1202', eSalary: '1300' },
    ],
    showFlag: true,
  };
  //arrow function will auto bind
  inputChangeHandler = (eName, id) => {
    this.setState({
      products: this.state.products.map(p =>
        p.id === id ? { ...p, eName } : p
      ),
    });
  };
  //arrow function will auto bind
  deleteHandler = id => {
    this.setState({
      products: this.state.products.filter(
        p => p.id !== id
      ),
    });
  };

  showHideHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      showFlag: !this.state.showFlag,
    });
  };

  render() {
    let dp = null;
    if (this.state.showFlag === true) {
      dp = (
        <div className="App">
          {this.state.products.map((product, index) => {
            return (
              <Product
                key={product.id}
                {...product}
                remove={this.deleteHandler}
                inputChange={this.inputChangeHandler}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {dp}
        <hr />
        <button onClick={() => this.showHideHandler()}>
          show hide
        </button>
        <h2>{this.state.eName} </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//make this a pure component with React.memo
const Product = React.memo(function Product({
  remove,
  id,
  eName,
  inputChange,
}) {
  console.log('rendering:', id);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => remove(id)}>delete</button>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={eName}
        onChange={e => inputChange(e.target.value, id)}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
});



//render app
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also pass the `index` to your `Product` component,

```
{this.state.product.map((product,index) => {
  return (
    <Product
      eName={product.eName}
      eNo={product.eNo}
      eSalary={product.eSalary}
      key = {index}
      ind = {index}   //pass index here
      click ={this.deleteHandler.bind(this.index)}
      inputChange={this.inputChangeHandler.bind(this)}
    />
  )
})}
```

your `Product` component should be this **(as per your comment)**,

```
import React from 'react'
import './employee.css'
function Employee(props) { 
    return (
        <div className ="prod"> 
            <h1> Name:{props.eName}</h1> 
            <h2> Emp-No:{props.eNo}</h2> 
            <h3> Salary:{props.eSalary}</h3> 
            <button onClick ={props.click}> delete</button> 
            <input onChange={(e) => props.inputChange(e,props.ind)} value={props.eName} type="text"/>  //pass `event` & `index` to `inputChange` function here
        </div>
    ) 
}
export default Employee;
```